# Get rows in SQL Until sum of a column(purchase qty) exceed Closing stock qty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Purchase table and Closing Stock Table.

PURCHASE TABLE

[image]

AND CLOSING STOCK TABLE

[image]

I want to return all the rows from purchase table based on Transaction_Date desc  till the sum(Purchase_qty) exceeds the Closing_Stock from CLOSING STOCK TABLE table.

Suppose for Material_Code AB01 in Purchase table closing_stock is 42 in CLOSING STOCK TABLE table. In that case rows returned will be as below

[image]

As you can see sum(Purchase_qty) of first 4 records is 43 so it exceed 42. I don't want to show the last column. So logic will be when sum(Purchase_qty) exceed closing_stock stop there.

I have tried below query but that doesn't achieve the result. Any inputs is highly appreciated.

```
SELECT A.Material_Code,A.Transaction_Date, A.Purchase_qty, 
sum(A.Purchase_qty) OVER (ORDER BY Material_Code) AS total 
from Purchase A 
left join Closing_Stock B ON
A.Material_Code = B.Material_Code
where A.Purchase_qty <= B.Closing_Stock
order by A.Transaction_Date desc
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or sqlserver?

Comment: It is SQL Server @ttallierchio

Answer (score 2):

You are close:

```
select csp.*
from (select cs.Material_Code, p.Transaction_Date, p.Purchase_qty, 
             sum(p.Purchase_qty) OVER (ORDER BY cs.Material_Code) AS running_qty,
             cs.closing_stock
      from closing_stock cs left join
           Purchase p
           on cs.Material_Code = p.Material_Code
     ) csp
where running_qty - Purchase_qty < closing_stock
order by Transaction_Date desc;
```

Note:  This gives you up to the first transaction that exceeds the closing stock.  Omit the `- Purchase_qty` if you want the last that is less than the value.

Comment: It says invalid column qty

Answer (score 0):

In the "row id"=2 (In Purchase table) we can see "Purchase_qty"=12 but in the results table, the same row (id=2) has Purchase_qty=17. I guess, you made mistake somewhere.
In my example, you will find "17" in that row.

Here you have proper select:

```
select Material_Code, Purchase_qty, Transaction_Date 
from Purchase p  
where Transaction_Date >= isnull((
    select max(tr_d) from (
        select Material_Code mt_cod, Transaction_Date tr_d, sum(Purchase_qty) OVER (ORDER BY Transaction_Date desc) AS total
        from Purchase iw
        where iw.Material_Code=p.Material_Code  
    ) as query  
    where total >= (select i.Closing_Stock from Closing_Stock i where i.Material_Code=mt_cod)   
), cast('1900-1-1' as date))
order by 1, 3 desc
```

I focused to build all in one query like in your example and that's why query seems to be a little complicated. If you could built it in couple small queries (instead of one), it would be better for performance. It also depends how big tables you have.

Result of my query:

```
Material_Code   Purchase_qty    Transaction_Date
AB01    6   2017-08-30 11:05:00.000
AB01    11  2017-08-30 11:04:00.000
AB01    9   2017-08-30 11:03:00.000
AB01    17  2017-08-30 11:02:00.000
AB05    29  2017-08-30 11:08:00.000
AB05    44  2017-08-30 11:07:00.000
AB05    22  2017-08-30 11:06:00.000
```

Data to check my query:

```
create table Purchase(Material_Code varchar(10), Purchase_qty integer, Transaction_Date datetime)
insert Purchase values
('AB01',22,'2017-08-30 11:01:00'),
('AB01',17,'2017-08-30 11:02:00'),
('AB01',9 ,'2017-08-30 11:03:00'),
('AB01',11,'2017-08-30 11:04:00'),
('AB01', 6,'2017-08-30 11:05:00'),
('AB05',22,'2017-08-30 11:06:00'),
('AB05',44,'2017-08-30 11:07:00'),
('AB05',29,'2017-08-30 11:08:00')

create table Closing_Stock(Material_Code varchar(10),Closing_Stock integer)
insert Closing_Stock values
('AB01',42),
('AB05',142)
```